# Accessing attributes of a list of objects in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of objects, known as `Bricks`, I want to check the attributes of all objects in the list. I tried:

```
pos = [Brick.start_pos for Brick in self.brick_list]
```

to create a list of the required attribute i.e `start_pos`, but it populates a list with only the attribute of the last brick in the brick_list. I am using python 3.4. I need to do this for a lot of different attributes so a comprehension makes sense to me.

Brick class is mostly just a holder for data and is defined:

```
class Brick:
    def __init__(self, start_pos=0, current_pos=0, variety=0, moveability=0, 
                 neighbours=0, max_range=0, sides=0, rotation=0, length=0,
                 previous_pos =0):
        self.start_pos = start_pos
        self.current_pos = current_pos
        self.moveability = moveability
        self.variety = variety
        self.neighbours = neighbours
        self.max_range = max_range
        self.sides = sides
        self.rotation = rotation
        self.length = length
        self.previous_pos = previous_pos
```

with couple very simple functions.

Comment: How did you define the class `Brick`? And how did you build the list?

Comment: The list is held as an attribute in another class. It is built by hell.brick_list = len(lister)*[Brick()]

Comment: The fragment that you have is a 100% correct list comprehension which yields the attributes of all the bricks in the brick_list (as long as accessing that attribute doesn't modify the list as a side effect). If it isn't giving you what you expect -- the problem is probably that the list isn't what you think that it is.

Comment: How did you build `self.brick_list` ?

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have looked into the list but I will look again.

Comment: @Elwood168 It appears the list contains the same `Brick` instance, repeated n times (n being the length of `lister`).

Comment: 'for i in range (len(lister)):
    hell.brick_list[i].start_pos = lister[i]'

Comment: How did you define `lister`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the list contains the same Brick instance, repeated n times (n being the length of lister)

```
hell.brick_list = len(lister)*[Brick()]
```

instead, you might want to build the list as

```
hell.brick_list = [Brick() for _ in lister]
```

Obviously, you will need to pass the constructor all the necessary parameters, otherwise you would end-up with Bricks with identical attributes (default values).

Actually, given your second comment

```
for i in range (len(lister)): hell.brick_list[i].start_pos = lister[i]
```

the best option would be to create and initialize the list all in one go

```
hell.brick_list = [Brick(start_pos=pos) for pos in lister]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that, in the first (non-working) version, this means that in the line `for i in range (len(lister)): hell.brick_list[i].start_pos = lister[i]` each time you assign a value to `start.pos` it is assigned to *all copies* of the same `Brick` instance, because they are all the same object.

Comment: @Pynchia. Thanks for the explanation, I did not understand that could happen. I replaced that line with what you suggested and it all worked immediately, very satisfying :)

Comment: `[Brick()]` is evaluated and it produces a list containing a single object instance. Then the list is multiplied by `len(lister)`, which produces a list containing the very same elements, but repeated `len(lister)` times over. Only one Brick object instance is created.

Comment: @SiHa yes. And thank you for mentioning that, I had not noticed  the OP's second comment, so you allowed me to improve my answer.